# Unique constraint on 42 Columns? Why should or shouldn't I consider doing this?

Tags: sql, sql-server, constraints

#### Theoretical:

I've been tasked with building a database to contain guidelines for manufacturing purposes.  The guidelines to be returned are based on 42 input values and are all specific to the particular combination of inputs.

I plan on indexing all of these columns and realize that it will be resource intensive if I have to rebuild or re-index.

- What design approaches have I not considered?
- What potential problems exist with the approach of creating a unique constraint on 42 columns?
- Does anyone have any experience with this sort of a design or any insights?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Are all 42 columns germane to every type of "thing"? (I doubt it)

Comment: *I plan on indexing all of these columns*
Most DBMS's will *automatically* add indexes on columns with unique constraints.

Comment: I would have a 'unique key' column that could be a json representation of the object, a carefully constructed hash of the properties or something and have the unique index on that one column.  Then, create indexes around how the data is to be accessed which likely wouldn't include all 40 columns.

Comment: I would suggest to read on the subject of Database Normalization, then pose a question. Here is Wikipedia to start https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization

Comment: I've worked in a few manufacturing facilities and the end goal is usually in different stages like pre-production, production, and post production.  Then the widget being manufactured may have a type... it would be good to see an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good reason for not doing it is that SQL Server doesn't support it:

> Up to 32 columns can be combined into a single composite index key.

(documentation [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188783.aspx)).

It seems unlikely that you really need a single composite index with 42 columns.  But, you can't have one even if that were desirable.

Comment: Well, another server could be used...

Answer (score 0):

1. Put index only on columns which will be searched/sorted.
2. Add simple autoincrement index.